# Printf not working

Tags: java, printf

I started to learn Java programming a while back, but never got very far, now I am starting back up again but have stumbled upon a problem.

`double c =0.000001;
System.out.printf("%4.3f",c);`

When I type the above code into Eclipse it gives me an error message under printf saying change type c to object. What am I doing wrong? And sorry if this a dumb question however I have looked around the internet and have not found any answers.

Comment: What version of Java are you using?

Comment: I believe I am running Java 8 developer kit.

Comment: Right-click your project, go to properties, go to Java Compiler, choose version 1.8.

Comment: I don't have 1.8 but, 1.7 appears to have worked.

Comment: Provide your stacktrace

Comment: ...and why not the whole class, you may be missing some syntax that trips the compiler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code works fine with autoboxing (double is autoboxed to Double under the hood). If you get this error message, it looks like that you're executing your code with a JVM version < 1.5 (without autoboxing).

Comment: The root cause isn't autoboxing. It's varargs which were also introduced in Java 5. The method is expecting a `Object[]` and they are providing a `double`.